# Change position of logo and search box in Magento 2 luma theme?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 I want to put the search box on the left side and the logo in the center on the Luma theme.

XML and CSS is fine changes are fine.

I have tried all the recommended solutions I found, but they screw up the responsive theme with CSS change only.

I also tried moving the block:

```
<move element="block.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="logo" />
```

Then changed the float to left for the search box.

But that did nothing. The search box is still right of the logo.

Comment: do you have any custom theme or you want to in default theme?